Maui how to bind commands in CollectionView items
How can I set any command in CollectionView to a command in the view model?
For example:
public partial class ItemsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public Command BuyItemCommand { get; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        BuyItemCommand = new(BuyItem);
    }

    public void BuyItem()
    {
        // some logic
    }
}

But in this case, I can't set any command of any item in the CollectionView.
And I can't put the command to the Item class because it is shared with the backend and used as model for the database
